# WSO2 ESB How to use JMSReplyTo with OUT_ONLY for making synchronous behaviour with two proxies.

Tags: jms, wso2-esb

I have use case like JMS client post message -> Queue1 and wait for reply of TEMP Queue and ESB Listens on Queue1 and post to -> Service Queue2 and Service should respond back to XXX Queue3 from there a different ESB should Listen on queue3 and post back response to temp Queue.

For this I want to change JMSReplyTo as Queue3 at insequence. Tried in below ways.
added property

```
<property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default"
   type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property action="set" name="JMSReplyTo"
   scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Queue3"/>
```

Now JMSReplyTo is created as text property of the message but ESB set JMReplyTo is as null in header. because of that Service is not replying back the response to Queue3. Please let me know the way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not set OUT_ONLY property for synchronous requests. 
Axis2 JMS transport will not set this JMS header for your message while OUT_ONLY is set to TRUE.
You can check this in sendOverJMS method of org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender class.